# "Cannot call method 'open' of undefined" error when using indexedDB.open

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am new to IndexedDB and I am following this guide [IndexedDB Tutorial](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html#slide30) I am simply trying to create a database and then be able to add a few entries. This is what I have so far.

```
var db = window.indexedDB.open('FriendDB', 'My Friends!');

if (db.version != '1') {
    // User's first visit, initialize database (name, key, auto increment).
    db.createObjectStore('Friends', 'id', true);
    db.setVersion('1');
} else {
  // DB already initialized.
}

var store = db.openObjectStore('Friends');
var user = store.put({name: 'Eric', gender: 'male', likes: 'html5'});
```

In my console I get the error "Cannot call method 'open' of undefined" how can I get this working? Also if there is a better resource online that would help me because I can't seem to find anything on the topic of IndexedDB for a newbie.

Comment: Visit this link Links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154905(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB is a good introductory tutorial. Also keep in mind that the standard has changed relatively recently, so old tutorials might have broken parts and different browsers might have different implementations (Firefox is currently the best, Chrome is lagging a bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the indexeddb demo from html5rocks which i have improved to work on Mozilla Firefox and added features for viewing details data and editing existing data. Inside you have explanations how to create db, insert, update and delete data in indexeddb.

https://github.com/denimf/IndexedDbToDo

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see code containing a call to setVersion, it's using an outdated syntax. It was unfortunate that we had to make such a big change so late during the spec writing, but it made using IndexedDB correctly tremendously simpler so we decided it was worth it.

There is good documentation on developer.mozilla.org, even though it could definitely be improved.

Comment: onupgradeneeded method still doesn't work in chrome, so the only way to upgrade the database is with setVersion function.

Comment: for anyone looking at this, onupgradeneeded event now works on current versions of Chrome.